# Where can I find the latest information on icon sizes for Android tab bars?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I found this site so far:

https://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

but I am looking for more information and hoping that Google publish some recommended official sizes.

Can anyone point me to a place where I can find more about Android icon sizes and specifically for tab bars?

Comment: icon size info https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications . About tab bar, it ups to style you gonna use. E.g. material design tab spec https://material.io/design/components/tabs.html#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/design/iconography/system-icons.html#) (if you're following it) are quite extensive and provide different scenarios that I've found quite useful over the years. I guess the System Icons section would apply to you best right now